# Intellisense after a backspace action in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I am fairly new to visual studio and i got to say this is by far the best IDE ever!
Just wondering if there is a add on or some type of customization in VS for this use case:

I type Conso and intellesense brings up all the options under that combination of code. and i hit tab for console, then i start .Wri and it brings up all the options again but i hit tab for "Write" and not "WriteLine" now when i hit backspace intellisense is not active until i remove everything from the including the "." then i have to start over .

It would be nice if i could just as i backspace give me the options so that i could select "WriteLine" without all the backspaces.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Space</kbd> to force Intellisense predictions at anytime.

Comment: Awesome. This IDE just gets better and better. Its such a pleasure to work in.

Answer (score 3):

There also is an option to show completion list after a character is deleted (often by pressing backspace).

Tools->Options->Search for "Intellisens"-> check "show completion list after a character is deleted"

[The option I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4rS9.jpg)